# Novice Ubuntu 12.04 user needs help!

Tags: ubuntu, java, desktop-environment, icons, dvd

Someone suggested I try Ubuntu. I like it but I can't figure a couple of things out and don't really have time to google up ways to solve the problem. Answers from a quick search were so confusing. Can someone provide me with a straightforward set of instructions with easy places to click and download packages for the following problems:

1) I manually placed an icon on the Ubuntu desktop. I want to remove it but can't figure out how! When I delete it, it's completely unaccessible on the original left side tool bar.

2) Where/How do I install Java for Ubuntu 12.04?

3) Where/How to I install a de-coder that will let me play a regular movie DVD?

4) How do I go back to installation options and allocate more computer space for Ubuntu and less for Windows?

Comment: Instead of posting one question made up of 4 unrelated questions, you probably want to post four separate questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are always multiple solutions, but here are how I would do things

On 1) I have no advice as I am running the Classic Desktop. There is a specific Ubuntu forum on SE [here](https://askubuntu.com/)

2) You use the Ubuntu Software Center, search for Java, install 'OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime'

3) You use the Ubuntu Software Center, search for VLC, install 'VLC Media Player'
This has all the codecs to play a regular movie DVD

4) You cannot 'go back to installation options'. For the most usual setup (Windows partition was shrunk and Linux put behind it), you cannot solve this without backing up and deleting the Linux partition, shrinking the Windows partition and then put things back. That can be done but AFAIK not from the running Linux installation. Reinstalling is probably going to be easier.